# difference at pipe and console

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe

I have the following program:

```
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    "ourhdr.h"

int     glob = 6;       /* external variable in initialized data */
char    buf[] = "a write to stdout\n";

int
main(void)
{
    int     var;        /* automatic variable on the stack */
    pid_t   pid;

    var = 88;
    if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf)-1) != sizeof(buf)-1)
        err_sys("write error");
    printf("before fork\n");    /* we don't flush stdout */

    if ( (pid = fork()) < 0)
        err_sys("fork error");
    else if (pid == 0) {        /* child */
        glob++;                 /* modify variables */
        var++;
    } else
        sleep(2);               /* parent */

    printf("pid = %d, glob = %d, var = %d\n", getpid(), glob, var);
    exit(0);
}
```

I can't explain the differences found at the exit of the program for the two executions (with and without redirection).

What I understand so far is buffering to `printf`.  When we redirect standard output to a ﬁle, however, we get two copies of the `printf` line. In this second case, the `printf` before the `fork` is called once, but the line remains in the buffer when `fork` is called. This buffer is then copied into the child when the parent’s data space is copied to the child.The second `printf`,right before the `exit`,just appends its data to the existing buffer.

The most important question I have is: the difference when writing on the screen(exit the console) and when writing in the pipe?

Answer (score 1):

When writing to the console the standard C library flushes output buffers at every newline, aka `"\n"`.

With any other device, output is only flushed when the buffer is full.

And you have it correct: fork() duplicates the output buffer.